# Android: Detect that user opens status bar

Tags: android, gps, detect, statusbar

I am writing an app that uses GPS for localization services. When the user tries to use the app with a disabled GPS, a dialog pops up. Now, the user can minimize the app and change the GPS settings. When he reopens the app, it detects in onResume() that the settings were changed and closes the dialog. 
That works fine, but the user has a second way to enable GPS: the status bar. When the status bar is opened and closed, neither onResume() nor onWindowFocusChanged() gets called, so that I don't detect when the user enabled GPS.

Is there a way to detect the opening of the status bar?

I could do it via the LocationListener, but I would like to do it how I wrote above.

Thanks in advance!

---

I found help at android-dev IRC. Now, I am using an Observer to notice setting changes like [here](http://pastebin.com/Z9mDZip4). So, I detect all setting changes, even if they are done via the notifications bar, without requesting updates from the LocationManager.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For listening to GPS that user has enabled, using a status bar, you can setup a listener for changes via the  location manager:

```
private class DisabledGPSListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener);
    }
```

set this listener inside onCreate()

```
if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener);
}else{
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, new DisabledGPSListener());
}
```

where gpsStatusListener is instance of:

```
    private class GPSStatuslistener implements GpsStatus.Listener {

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            Log.d(TAG, "ongpsstatus changed started");
            //TODO: your code that get location updates, e.g. set active location listener 
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            Log.d(TAG, "ongpsstatus changed stopped");
            createGpsDisabledAlert();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it LocationManager.addGpsStatusListener you are looking for?

Comment: I thought both are managed by the same engine... Cannot check right now

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but no, I don't think so. This listener detects only GPS changes, right? It does not detect providers getting enabled. BTW, I am using GPS _and_ AGPS (I forgot to add it). And actually, I don't want to use a GPS listener; I want to detect, when the user opens the status bar. I think this reduces battery consumption (instead of requesting updates from the LocationManager).  -deleted my first comment, I was to slow to edit-

Comment: Maybe it's the same engine, but the engine is not started when the user just enables GPS. So, `onGpsStatusChanged(int event)` doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly address your issue, but you may find it easier to open the settings for the user:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: I will think about this, but actually I don't really want to force the user to enable GPS. I just want to notice when he does so.

Comment: ok well just check on OnResume() and display a dialog. This dialog gives the choice to enable gps (thus starting this activity) or dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Yeah, but the user can still open the status bar to enable GPS and the app wouldn't notice it. So, no one has an idea how to detect that a user opens/closes the status bar??